# Fluid simulation using imported .stl files does not function properly

Tags: import, fluid-simulation

I am importing a .stl file of a hollow component with multiple openings. I want fluid to flow through the model as if it were a pipe. I have tried different combinations of treating the obstacle as a surface, volume, or both with each resulting in weird behavior. Basically the fluid will not flow through the imported .stl part or the baking process will show no result at all.

Am I missing something for the setup of the scene? I tried recalculating normals which did nothing and the geometry is very simple. Any advice or suggestions would be helpful.

[image: Image of the fluid flowing around the pipe]

I'm aware that this shape could easily be made in Blender and did not need to be imported as an .stl however, this is a just a demonstration of the issue that I have. The fluid does not flow through the pipe, despite being directly flowed over its other end. It's like the model is being treated a single solid object, no matter how I define the obstacle (surface, volume, both).

Comment: Upload your file. We can't really help you unless you include screen shots and or upload a file.

Comment: Added an image for clarity of explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that you are having is that your fluid is not a high enough resolution. Try changing the resolution slider in your fluid physics tab up to 100 or 150.

Comment: That did it, I had to crank the resolution up to 250 but it solved the issue. Many thanks!